# What is the diffrence between isEqualToString and operator == in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c

```
if(lyricsId == areleased.trackId)

{
  ----------;
  ----------;
}
```

when i am working with above code it does not entered into that loop So, I used the below code,then it entered into the loop and i got out put.

```
if([lyricsId isEqualToString:areleased.trackId])
{
    ----------;
    ----------;

}
```

Is there any difference between == and isEqualToString.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`lyricsId` and `arelease.trackId` are (I presume) of type `NSString*`. The `==` simply compares the pointers, which will usually be different even if their contents are the same. The `isEqualToString` method compares their contents.

Answer (score 5):

`==` will compare pointers(addresses)  equality, while `isEqualToString:`will compare if one string is equal to another.